# BayesOptSearch cant be imported even after installation

Tags: python, pip, ray

I wanted to try the new BayesOpt Search from the Ray package. I followed the directions from the [Ray documentation](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tune-searchalg.html#bayesopt-search) and installed the Bayesian Optimization package.

I used jupyter notebook to import and start the Tune Trials without problem. But even after I installed the necessary package it still says it cannot be imported.

I tried this :

```
from ray.tune.suggest import BayesOptSearch
```

Installation is in a pyenv with python 3.6.5 and i checked 10 times if it is the right environment I installed it.

Any suggestions what i am missing?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  When posting questions about Python errors, it helps if you add a snippet of the stack trace.

Comment: What version of Ray are you using? Can you try installing a snapshot of the latest master? https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: @richliaw Removing my answer as it does not address the question -- thank you